# Flutter build apk on release mode get stuck on launch screen

Tags: flutter

When I run `flutter build apk --debug`, When I install the app on a physical device, my app works and loads fine.

But when I run `flutter build apk --release` or `flutter build apk --no-shrink --split-per-abi`

I get this output

```
Building with sound null safety 

Parameter format not correct -
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.4.31/84ce8e85f6e84270b2b501d
44e9f0ba6ff64fa71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.31/a58e0fb9812a6a93ca24b5da75e4
b5a0cb89c957/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.31/6dd50665802f54ba9bc3f
70ecb20227d1bc81323/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.31/e613be5465ef1e6fd046870
7690b7ebf625ea2fe/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.31.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.10/6b84d926e28493be69daf
673e40076f89492ef7/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.10/6229be3465805c99db114
2ad75e6c6ddeac0b04c/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.10.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.10/ea29e063d2bbe695be13e9d044dc
fb0c7add398e/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar (version 1.4)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.10/c49d0703d16c6cb1526cc07
b9b46486da1dd8a60/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.10/da6a904b132f0402fa4d79169a3c
1770598d4702/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1094.6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (47.8MB).
```

And when I install the app on my physical device, the App gets stuck on the launch screen.

What might be the issue?

Comment: if your device requires any permission then add that permission to androidManifest.xml

Comment: @Jahidul Islam All permissions needed are added in the androidManifest.xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: clean and run flutter and delete your previous version too

Comment: @Jahidul Islam What previous version should I delete?

Comment: previously installed apps from your phone